# System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable.

Tags: asp.net, iis

I get this error when trying to send an email using Asp.net application using SMTP on IIS 7.5

The error is "System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such user here at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(... "

What i have in web.config is

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp from="support@mysite.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
<network host="hostname" port="25" password="password" userName="you@yoursite.com" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I really don't understand what should be the username and password here. I get the same error when i put defaultcredentials = "true" instead of username and password. Is there something to do with toaddress. The toaddress is myid@mydomain.com, which works for all other emails, etc.

Please advice me where i am doing wrong!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userName` and `password` settings refer to the credentials for connecting to the *SMTP server*. Make sure you don't confuse this with the username and password for the `from` or `to` address, which is not relevant to the SMTP server.

You may want to try a tool like [SMTPDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BC1881C7-925D-4A29-BD42-71E8563C80A9&displaylang=en) to help you figure out any SMTP connectivity issues you have. However, your error seems to indicate that connectivity is fine but that mail cannot be delivered.

Comment: Can you please tell me where i can find the credentials for connecting to the SMTp server? Because i have used the email ID's with mailbox setup, and i still ahve the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about configuring SMTP or your setup. If you're using IIS as a virtual SMTP server, you can look at its settings in the IIS management UI. It's probably set up to forward to a real SMTP server. Perhaps you have Exchange set up to do that, and I have no experience with that. You should consider asking your question on serverfault.com. Good luck!

Comment: MY God!! You were right. Though i have the mailbox setup done, it was still giving the error but when i used a gmail account as "To", it worked. Wasted 2 days on this. Thanks alot :-)

Comment: The SMTPDiag tool is no longer available from Microsoft. Link is broken. However it seems like it can be obtained from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

Ram if you are using a web host and you have SMTP support in your package... Then check their control panel.

Also as Jacob I want to remind you that FREE SMTP user accounts that web hosts offer are different from credentials to connect to the SMTP server itself. Usually the former is that's free with web hosts and the latter is not included as long as you don't have a dedicated server I think.

If you don't find it in their control panel then call support... They will be able to give you those details if applicable.

Comment: You make complete sense! Thank you very much for the insight!